# Make middle View not push other view outside of bounds

Tags: android

I have multiple TextViews inside a horizontal LinearLayout and i need the middle text view to have ellipse=middle so that when the middle text is long enough, it pushes on both sides but the other views don't go out of bounds, but instead the middle TextView shows the '..."

[image]

Here's how it should look.

[image]

Setting the items normally, wrap_content for all in a horizontal LinearLayout will make the `at ASAP` text be pushed outside of the screen on Android (the above screens are from the iOS app).

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Perhaps with a ConstraintLayout somehow ?!

Comment: Could you comment the relevant android layout code? Because a LinearLayout with proper weights and attributes should be able to achieve this just fine

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i would recommend a ConstraintLayout.  Top item to the top of the view, bottom item to thr bottom of the view then the middle item attached to these two views. You could also use barriers.

Comment: Could you give me an example, please? I'm not that familiar with ConsstraintLayouts and I don't really want to waste a lot of time with this :(